# Scene is noisy and the noise barely changes from 750+ samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

I have created this blockout of a hobbit hole but when i try to render it it's very slow and quite noisy(denoising used) even without volumetrics. I would just crank up the samples to solve this but the noise barely changes from 700+ samples. I thought it might had to do somthing with light bounces but changing those doesn't make a difference. Also tried using portals but they actually made it even worse.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cycles is a ray-traced render engine. Noise is normal. You have to increase the sample count and use denoiding to remove the noise. There is no other way.

Comment: I understand that, this was rendered at 1250 samples and denoised, it's just that this simple geometry shouldn't produce this much noise and take so long to render

Comment: Noise will still be there even if you go upto 100,000 samples. You need to use denoising now that the feature is here. And about the rendering time, that depends on your hardware.

Comment: Again, this was denoised, and my hardware renders a scene with 3 times more geometry, complicated lighing and many metallic materials about 5 times faster than it renders this.

Comment: So if that's your problem, you can try uploading your .blend file so the scene can be checked in detail.

Comment: It should now be linked in the question. Now that i'm thinking about it it might just the indirect lighting bouncing around the room and causing a lot of noise

Comment: Yes it does, thank you